# Cannot import matplotlib module after installing cython

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cython, cythonize

To speed up certain resource-intensive Python functions, I'm using Cython. However, after using cython, I've seen that importing the matplotlib.pyplot module takes more than 2-3 minutes, whereas importing just "matplotlib" is instant. I'm guessing Cython messed up some matplotlib.pyplot operations. After importing matplotlib.pyplot if I hit ctrl+c I receive an error as

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/raghvender/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2230, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/home/raghvender/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 672, in __getitem__
    plt.switch_backend(rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel)
  File "/home/raghvender/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 225, in switch_backend
    current_framework = cbook._get_running_interactive_framework()
  File "/home/raghvender/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 89, in _get_running_interactive_framework
    if not _c_internal_utils.display_is_valid():
KeyboardInterrupt
```

To me it appears that it is stuck in some cbook module. I tried removing cython module, reinstalling matplotlib but none of them worked. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me where these two packages are interfering.

PS : I need Cython to perform some heavy calculation.

Comment: Are you using `pyximport`? I'm really not sure they should interfere: matplotlib doesn't use Cython and Cython doesn't change the import mechanism (unless you've deliberately used `pyximport`...)

Comment: [This looks similar](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22385)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No I am not using pyximport. This is my setupy.py file ```from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("distance_minkowski_reduction.pyx"),
 include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
``` And then I use, "python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace". I tried this in two different linux computer and same issue. For the moment, I deleted everything related to matplotlib in '.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib*' and did a fresh install of matplotlib without cython and now its working fine.

Comment: If you want a proper answer to this it seems like it needs a full [mre] really to clarify exactly what you need to do to reproduce this starting from a completely clean virtual-env. For example, it's currently unclear if this problem happens as soon as you install Cython (in which case your setup.py is irrelevant), as soon as you run setup.py, as soon as you import your Cython module, or when importing matplotlib from within your Cython module.